# Calling sub-function (local function) from another file on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to figure out how to properly call a sub function from another .m file. I've searched for documentation, and only found the way of using function handles (as can be seen here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/call-local-functions-using-function-handles.html)

The thing is that I think I've managed to find a way to it without using function handles, and want to know what am i doing and how does it works:

```matlab
on main.m file:

function main
%function main...
end

function z = sub_function(x,y)
%function sub_function...
end

on outside.m file:
function call_to_local_function_from_outside
z = main('sub_function', x,y);
end
```

Appernalty, this is working, but I need to know why?

Comment: can you add the matlab version

Comment: I suppose there is a piece of code in `main` function that makes it work. Dose the main function execute `str2func`?

Comment: This is a classical way of calling subfunctions, which we used before there were function handles. It was useful mostly to collect graphics callbacks into a single M-file. This requires that `main` parse its arguments and call the appropriate sub-function.

Comment: Please read [mre]. Your code, as written, generates an error message when I type `main('sub_function',1,2)` ("Too many input arguments."). If you want to make a point of this actually working, do include the working code.